# Rails Model user adding player to user pinboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, activerecord, model

I'm creating a sports application which allows users to create pinboards, as many as they like. The users can then add say their favorite player to a specified pinboard. So for example
User: Jack, creates a new pinboard called "My favorite defenders", He can then go and find his favorite defenders, say Kevin Garnet, and add/pin garnet to his "My favorite defenders" Pinboard.

I have a Users model, a Pinboards Model and a Players model. I tried the following association but didn't work as I wanted.

User

```
has_many :pinboards
has_many :pins, through: pinboards, source: :player
```

Pinboard

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :player
```

I know a player can't have many pinboards and a pinboard will hold many players. How can I get the behavior i want; User creates pinboard---user adds player to pinboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User

has_many :pin_boards
has_many :pins, through: :pin_boards, source: :players


PinBoard

belongs_to :user
has_many :pin_board_player_assignments
has_many :players, through: :pin_board_player_assignments


PinBoardPlayerAssignment

belongs_to :pin_board
belongs_to :player


Player

has_many :pin_board_player_assignments
has_many :pin_boards, through: :pin_board_player_assignments
```

So, basically, you'll need to add another model called `PinBoardPlayerAssignment`. From there, I'd highly recommend using this join model to create and manage the assignments, like so:

```
PinBoardPlayerAssignment

def self.create_between(a_pin_board, a_player)
  assignment = a_pin_board.pin_board_player_assignments.build
  assignment.player = a_player
  assignment.save!
end
```

This way, you can use instance methods on `PinBoard` **or** on `Player` to DRYly create the assignment between the PinBoard and the Player. Basically, let the object that knows the most about pin_boards and players be the one to manage the relationships between them.

```
PinBoard

def add_player(a_player)
  PinBoardPlayerAssignment.create_between(self, a_player)
end


Player

def add_to_pin_board(a_pin_board)
  PinBoardPlayerAssignment.create_between(a_pin_board, self)
end
```

And the great thing is that Rails 3.2+ allows nested :through relationships so your original request -- to have `@user.pins` should compile the result of going through the pin_board and then through the pin_board_player_assignment table automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
has_many :pins, through: :pin_boards, source: :players
```

The key is to make the `source` be the exact same as the relationship in the join model. So, since your join model (PinBoard) almost certainly says `has_many :players` then you have to match that word `players` exactly. So you were just missing the 's'.

Comment: Thanks pdobb, technically that works, but still not as I expect. My goal is this. i'd like to have a user create a new pinboard and probably call add_player method on the users_pinboard, where add_player is an instance method in the pinboard class would take a player object argument and set the player_id of pinboard table to the player.id argument. So when I do something like user.pins, I get a list of players added to the current_users, specified pinboard.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I will attempt a new answer!