# Should I worry about method reusing in a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Long time ago, I learned that you should write reusable methods on the model, so you wouldn't wind up with duplicate code across your application. Of course, this was using PHP, which isn't nearly as dynamic as ruby.

Now, I'm designing an API using Rails, and I still keep thinking about that. So, my question is: should I create a method `User.login(user, password)` or should I just use `User.find_by(user: user, password: password)`?

I used to like the method approach too because of some facilities that it gives us, like in the method login above. `password` usually should be encrypted somehow, and by creating the `login` method I could encapsulate that.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you want to define methods on objects and call them from other objects. This is a key tenant of Object Oriented programming: message passing. Calling a method on an object lets that object handle its own internals. You don't want to manipulate or query on the internals of another object ever, if at all possible. Otherwise, when you change the internals of that object you now have to go change all the code that relied on those internals.

To illustrate using your example, if you one day change the User model's password attribute (i.e. column name) to, say, `encrypted_password` then the `User.login(user, password)` method wouldn't need to change at all, but the `User.find_by(user: user, password: password)` method would. So this is creating brittle code!

Be [DRY, Shy, and tell the other guy](http://media.pragprog.com/articles/may_04_oo1.pdf)!

#### UPDATE

In Rails you will find people often using Rails' Active Record Query Interface to replace common functions on objects, like getters and setters based on multiple attributes. This is generally accepted as OK because, mass-assignment for example, can greatly simplify your code. And because, in a way, `User.find_by(user: user, password: password)` actually is a message being passed to the `User` class. I agree with your concerns about this and think that generally, at least a named scope should be defined to take care of this. And/or creating class methods for building object relationships should be utilized as often as makes sense (see, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18553387/171183) I wrote on this subject a while back). There just is a bit of looseness when building Rails model relationships. I think this probably came from 2 things: 1) DHH (the creator of Rails) isn't huge on pure object modeling concepts and abstraction over simplicity/readability of code, and 2) I think that in the beginning most Rails apps were kind of toy apps and people got used to not thinking about engineering them too strongly. But, either way, do what you feel is right based on your own level of comfort with the trade-offs.

Comment: The problem is, I see many, many programmers that don't follow this approach. They ORM everything. So, I agree with what you said (nice link, btw), but I recently realized that ruby is a whole new world, that I don't know how to fully explore yet. That's what was bugging me, why programmers don't use this approach in rails code.

Comment: Well that's what makes the difference between novice programmers and "expert" programmers -- understanding and *implementing* good coding practices. It's easier to understand than to apply the implementation, though (it takes effort!). So you get some laziness mixed in with some "this is good enough for now". I'm going to update my answer to include a little more on why this particular issue happens in Rails a lot.

Comment: I think if it's something you know you're going to use multiple places, make life easier on yourself and encapsulate this logic so you only update one area of code instead of a handful. I think you see examples of duplication of common actions because sometimes it's hard to have the foresight that certain actions will need to occur multiple places, and the programmer doesn't take the time to refactor previous code to use a new interface.

Comment: I think @keith's comment sums up the pervasive Rails opinion nicely. The point being that the Rails community tends to prefer quick and easy code over the harder, more-time-consuming, but, better designs (largely by calling less tightly coupled code premature optimization, perhaps). And this isn't necessarily bad since getting your product to market is what matters in the end -- not having beautiful code. And you can always refactor pain points from this technical debt in the future. See also: https://medium.com/@joaomilho/festina-lente-e29070811b84

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You almost certainly want to use a gem like [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) that will provide these sorts of methods for you.

Comment: Sure devise adds a lot of this functionality, but I think the example above was just to give an example to a more generic approach throughout the project.

Comment: Although writing small reusable methods is generally a good thing.

Comment: @Keith, exactly. And I do use Devise, awesome gem!